# Clarification about PHP PDO Select for Update Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, pdo, transactions

I am new to using transactions.

Basically, I am able to successfully lock a single row in the MySQL console using `START TRANSACTION` followed by a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement.  The row remains locked until I run the `COMMIT` command in the console

However, when I do the same in a PHP script using `$db->beginTransaction()` followed by `$db->execute("SELECT ... FOR UPDATE")`, the row does not get locked before I run a `$db->commit()` script.

What I mean is I can still successfully do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement in the console even before I run a commit script in PHP to end the transaction.  Does this mean my PHP script is not successfully locking the row during the transaction?  How am I able to check?

Comment: Are you sure your transaction is still open and not already closed by commit when you try and check on the console? Might be a problem with isolation levels, so that the defaults aren't the same for your first and your second example... Perhaps this can help to find out if they're different? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347567/view-isolation-level-for-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: I just tested it again.  I am absolutely positive I did not close the transaction through PHP because I do not have `$db->commit()` anywhere in my script.  But why am I able to start other transactions before I close the current one in PHP?  This problem does not occur when I do transactions in the console.  Does PHP automatically close the transaction for me even without running the `commit()` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP respectively PDO automatically closes and rolls back open transactions after the script has ended, and for very good reasons - generally, you do not want transactions staying open after the `PHP` parsing ends. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back. This is a safety measure to help avoid inconsistency in the cases where the script terminates unexpectedly--if you didn't explicitly commit the transaction, then it is assumed that something went awry, so the rollback is performed for the safety of your data.

To test, you might add a `sleep(120)` after your `execute`, start the `PHP` script, switch to the `MySQL` console and issue statements there. I think you will experience the expected lock.