# Is this right way to do READ UNCOMMITTED? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Is this right way to do READ UNCOMMITTED?**

```
$cars = Cars
        ::raw('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;')
        ->Active()->get();
```

Comment: Have you run it? did you get any errors? If you want to check whether it did something: maybe interesting? : [View isolation level for a query in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347567/view-isolation-level-for-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: have you solved your problem maybe? How did you do it?

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
Cars::raw('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED');
```

and than

```
$cars = Cars::all();
```

to get all cars for example.

Comment: Hi, I am using Laravel 5.3.6, Can u help me ?

Comment: have you tried this answer? if yes, where is the problem and why it didn't work? and which sql version are you using?

Answer (score -7):

You should never use READ UNCOMMITTED unless you are generating random number and dont care about the data returned.

Comment: this is counter productive and question asks oposite thing.

Comment: The question is similar to "Is this right way to dereference uninitialized pointer?"
It's important to first understand that this is almost never what you really want to do.